# Posting out columns

Tags: php

For a school assignment, I need to make a blog system. I almost got it working but there is one problem my PHP will only send out one column instead of all of it.

```
<body>
<?php
require_once("nbbc/nbbc.php");

$bbcode = new BBCode;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY date DESC";

$res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

$posts = "";

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $date = $row['date'];

        $admin = "<div><a href='del_post.php?pid=$id'>Delete</a>&nbsp;<a href='edit_post.php?pid=$id'>Edit</a></div>";

        $output = $bbcode->Parse($content);

        $posts = "<div><h2><a href='view_post.php?pid=$id'>$title</a></h2><h3>$date</h3><p>$output</p>$admin</div>";
    }
    echo $posts;
} else {
    echo "Er zijn geen berichten te bekijken vandaag!";
}

    ?>
```

Comment: You are echoing `$posts` outside of your `while` loop. Move it inside of the `while` loop and you will likely get the results you are looking for.

Comment: You override `$posts` each time instead of appending to it. So it will only keep the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialised `$posts` before loop.

And you are supposed to append the output from loop to `$posts` in every iteration.

You are not concatenating your output in loop.

So, every time loop runs, the value of `$posts` gets updated to the latest one.

And hence, values from only last iteration will be shown as that is the latest one.

So, to add concatenation, please modify the following line to:

```
$posts .= "<div><h2><a href='view_post.php?pid=$id'>$title</a></h2><h3>$date</h3><p>$output</p>$admin</div>";
```

Please observe extra `.` before `=`, that is concatenation operator in PHP.